# How to generate a JAX-RS (RESTEasy) server for Java 7 using Swagger Codegen?

Tags: swagger, java-7, openapi, swagger-codegen

I have an OpenAPI YAML file loaded in https://editor.swagger.io and from there, I have generated the server code for jaxrs-resteasy.

The problem is this code must be integrated in a Java 7 project and Swagger Editor generates the code for Java 8.

Is there any way to generate the jaxrs-resteasy server code for Java 7?